Can I map two overlapping sets of numbers to a third set, in a way that the process can be reversed?
Imagine I have two sets of numberes
$A = \{1, 2, 3\}$
and
$B = \{2, 3, 4\}$
Is it possible to map these two sets to a third set
$X = \{1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006\}$
in a unique way, so that a number from $X$ can tell me if its "origin" is in set $A$ or set $B$, and which number it is?
One possible way is to let $A$ have the even numbers in $X$, and $B$ the uneven numbers in $X$, maybe.
Use-case is related to stores, receipts, and order numbers, if anyone is interested. :)
Thank you in advance.
(Feel free to add proper tags.)

Is it necessary for your second set to only have numbers? Can it have pairs of numbers as elements?

@HackR Hello, yes, X must be numbers sadly - it's just an integer in a database.

One way would be, as you said, to apply the map $x \mapsto 2x$ for numbers in $A$, and the map $x \mapsto 2x + 1$ to elements of $B$. Then, the parity tells you which set it came from, and upon (subtracting one if odd, then) dividing by 2, you get your original number back.

Then your idea (and as explained by blomp too) works perfectly.

Thank you. Let me double-check about possible other constraints on X as a number series. It's possible that it must be strictly increasing, without any gaps, per accounting laws... Then there might not be any pure mathematical solution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function
